# Check if OleDb database exists

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledb

I tried to look around but I failed to find anyone (even in SO) who explained how to check if an Access database exists or not using OleDb 12.0. I figured out how to create a database:

```
Catalog cat = new CatalogClass();
string cntPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string createStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + cntPath + "\\" + TB_LoginUsername.Text.ToLower() + "_LOG.accdb;";
cat.Create(createStr);
Table tbl = new Table();
tbl.Name = TB_LoginUsername.Text + "_SESSIONS";
tbl.Columns.Append("ID", DataTypeEnum.adGUID);
tbl.Columns.Append("Cycling", DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 25);
tbl.Columns.Append("Running", DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 25);
tbl.Columns.Append("Swimming", DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 25);
cat.Tables.Append(tbl);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(tbl);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat.Tables);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat.ActiveConnection);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(cat);
```

But I don't understand how to check if one exists or not - could anyone guide me how to do this? I'm suspecting it's something to do with `File.Exists()` but I don't know how to use it.

Thanks!

Comment: `if (!File.Exists(cntPath + "\\" + TB_LoginUsername.Text.ToLower() + "_LOG.accdb)) { /*do something about it*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working code to check if table exists:

```
try
{
        OleDbConnection myConnection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + frmMain.strFilePath + "\\ConfigStructure.mdb");
        myConnection.Open();
        OleDbCommand myCommand = new OleDbCommand();
        myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
        myCommand.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE <yourtable name>(<columns>)";
        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myCommand.Connection.Close();
}
catch(OleDbException e)
{  
    if(e.ErrorCode == 3010 || e.ErrorCode == 3012)
    // if error then table exist do processing as required
}
```

### UPDATE

If you wanna check database exists or not: You can use DTO , get a list of Database names, check for the one you need, and react appropriately or you can open your ADO connection. If you get an error opening the connection that says “datasource not found an no default driver specified” (from ODBC) or “[LNA][Pervasive][ODBC Engine Interface][Data Record Manager]Cannot locate the named database you specified(Btrieve Error 2301)” (from OLEDB), then the database doesn't exist.

You can use DTO to create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: He said to check if the **database** exists, not a table, so this won't help for the problem at hand.

Comment: Thanks but the code you posted is to check whether a table in the database exists or not, whereas I need to know how to check whether the database, as a whole, exists or not. =)